# bottom css property makes item dissappear

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm in a css firestorm trying to figure this out.

I have this code

```
.spectator-chat-title{
    background-color: darken($content-container-bg, 5%);
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #1C2337;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px darken($content-container-bg, 10%);
    z-index: 1001;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;

    &.collapse{
        bottom: 50px;
    }

}
```

then I have this ng-class method in my markup

```
<div class="spectator-chat-title" ng-class="{'collapse':chatHide}">
        <i ng-click="chatHide = !chatHide" ng-class="{'fa-angle-double-down':!chatHide, 'fa-angle-double-up':chatHide}" class="fa pull-right"></i>
</div>
```

When I'm in chrome dev tools and change the bottom property to 50px it works. But when I add the 'collapse' class through ng-click... the item just POOFS and disappears. Any ideas? '

Comment: What happen when you add the `collapse` class from dev tools (not just the bottom style)?

Comment: It disappeared as well. As if I hit the ng-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the comments, I don't know why exactly the item disappears, but if you say that it works with setting the bottom style directly, then you can do this instead:

```
<div class="spectator-chat-title" ng-style="{'bottom': chatHide ? '50px' : ''}">
```

Comment: sigh, this works. Thank you. I always go down the wrong rabbit hole when I think I messed something up.